# Azure DevOps Extension BuildDefinition Context

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I try to resolve the current buildDefinition context in an Azure DevOps Extension that targets "ms.vss-build-web.build-definition-detail-view".

The url is
`https://dev.azure.com/<orgnaization>/<project>/_build?definitionId=<buildDefinitionId>&view=<publisher>.<extension>`.

[image]

I am looking for something similar to resolving the current project context...

```
const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
const project = await projectService.getProject();
```

with respect to

```
"azure-devops-extension-api": "1.153.2"
"azure-devops-extension-sdk": "^2.0.11"
"azure-devops-ui": "2.166.97"
```

Any hints how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time, so maybe this is useful for another developer...

```
async componentDidMount() {
  SDK.init();
  await SDK.ready();    
  SDK.getConfiguration().onDefinitionChanged((buildDefinition: BuildDefinition) => ...);
}
```